# Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

I am looking at some code written for a custom object in Salesforce. When you are on the New or Edit screen, the code allows you to enter multiple records at one time by clicking an "Add Row" button, however there is not a "Delete Row" button so if you add one row too many, you have to enter bogus info and save and then go back in and delete the record out.  The fields that show up in the row are required fields so I thought that might be why I could not just add a function for "Delete Row" under "Add Row".  Any ideas on how I can get this to work properly? Do the fields need to be changed to not required to get this to work?

```
function insertOpp()
{
    var isInsert = j$("input:hidden[id$='isEnableOppSubmit']").val();
    if(isInsert == 'true')
    {
        blockScreen();
        insertOpportunity();
    }
}

function addAnotherOpportunity()
{
    blockScreen();
    addRow();
}

function resetForm()
{
     $(".error").removeClass("error");
}
```

Comment: Check this out, it must help you: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10903/removing-rows-separately-from-the-visualforce-pageblocktable-list

Comment: If you are having required field issue ,I would suggest to use jquery functions to add rows and delete rows and then javascript remoting to pick data filled in forms and send to controller for process and show errors back from server for those that failed .

Comment: This question needs a lot more information to be answerable, and it's not likely to be of use to anybody else if you're having problems with understanding particular existing code. Please edit it to add more information to show what the problem is, otherwise it will be closed as being too localized.

Comment: An alternate approach is to use a wrapper class on your Sobject with a property 'isDeleted'.  Each row of your table includes a delete commandlink, `immediate="true"` which sets the isDeleted to true, rerenders the table and isDeleted rows shown w/ strikethrough font. The struckthru line delete command then changes to Undelete, which if clicked, resets isDeleted to false and rerenders again.  Then, your save command can upsert all table rows that are isDeleted = false and delete all rows that are isDeleted = true if they have ids. Avoids javascript altogether