# I want to add records into a table in popup using Visualforce and apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="TestPopup">

<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:commandButton value="show popup" action="{!showPopup}" rerender="popup" status="status"/>



             <apex:outputPanel id="popup">

                <apex:outputPanel id="popInnerOutputPnl" styleClass="customPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
                     <apex:commandButton value="X" title="Close the popup" action="{!closePopup}" styleClass="closeButton" rerender="popup">
                     </apex:commandButton>
                     <apex:pageblockSection >                         

                         <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                          <apex:outputLabel value="Email" for="address"></apex:outputLabel>
                             <apex:inputField id="address" value="{!Contact.Email}"/>
                         </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                     </apex:pageblockSection>
                     <apex:commandButton value="Ok" action="{!redirectPopup}" styleClass="closeButton" rerender="popup">
                     </apex:commandButton>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:outputPanel>

            </apex:pageBlock>

              </apex:form>

                  <style type="text/css">
.customPopup {
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    /* These are the 3 css properties you will need to tweak so the pop 
                            up displays in the center of the screen. First set the width. Then set 
                            margin-left to negative half of what the width is. You can also add 
                            the height property for a fixed size pop up.*/
    width: 500px;
    top: 20%;
}

.disabledTextBox {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: black;
    cursor: default;
    width: 90px;
    display: table;
    padding: 2px 1px;
    text-align:right;
}   

.closeButton {
    float: right;
}
</style>


</apex:page>
```

Controller is:

```
public with sharing class TestPopup {

    public Boolean displayPopup {get;set;}

    public TestPopup(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    public void showPopup()
    {

    displayPopup = true;


    }

    public void closePopup() {
        displayPopup = false;

    }

    public PageReference redirectPopup()
    {
    displayPopup = false;
    return null;
        //Please uncomment below 3 statements and replace YourObjectId
       // PageReference p=new Pagereference('/'+YourObjectId);
       //  p.setRedirect(true);
       //  return p;

    }



}
```

This popup is working 100% fine. But i need to a table with headers and want to add new records manually.
eg:- if i am having 2 rows then i need 2 fill 2 rows and record must be saved in respective object.

Comment: Check out this topic: [Removing rows separately from the Visualforce pageBlockTable list](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10903/removing-rows-separately-from-the-visualforce-pageblocktable-list/10906#10906)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. But my functionality is not similar. When i click a button there must be a popup and add rows in a table.

Comment: @user4986 mast0r gave the link to get the idea meant that you need to start writing code based on this.

Comment: @user4986 , do you want like after you doing activity in the popup then it close the popup with the row being added into table in parent window?

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="quotation1Controller">

   <!--  <head>
        <style> 
            body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; }
            .companyName { font: bold 30px; color: red; }  
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <h1>New Account Name!</h1>

        <apex:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%">
            <apex:outputText value="{!Quotation1.Name}" styleClass="companyName"/>
            <apex:outputText value="{!NOW()}"></apex:outputText>

        </apex:panelGrid>
        </center>
    </body>
    -->

      <script type="text/javascript">
          function up() {

        //if (document.getElementById("srt").value != "") {
            var dop = document.getElementById(" Product_Name__c").value;
              alert(dop);
        //}
        function myFunction()

        {

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hello World";
        }
         </script>  
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Quotation"/>

  <apex:form >

 <apex:facet name="footer">
         <apex:commandButton action="{!step2}" value="Next"
                             styleClass="btn"/>
       </apex:facet>

        <apex:pageBlock >

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Quotation Information">

         <apex:inputField id="contactFirstName"
                          value="{!Quotation1.First_Name__c}"/>

         <apex:inputField id="contactMiddleName"
                          value="{!Quotation1.Last_Name__c}"/>                


           <apex:inputField id="contactLastName"
                            value="{!Quotation1.Date__c}"/>


           <apex:inputField id="contactAddress"
                           value="{!Quotation1.City__c}"/>

       <apex:inputField id="discount" value="{!Quotation1.Discount__c}"/>

         <apex:selectList label="Product Name" value="{!Quotation1.ProductName__c}"  multiselect="false" size="1">
                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
        </apex:selectList> 
         <apex:inputField id="contactZipCode"
                           value="{!Quotation1.Quantity__c}"/>

         <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Add" onclick="up()">

    </apex:commandButton>


         </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Product Table">
  <apex:dataTable value="{!Product}" var="pd" styleClass="outBorder" width="550px">

  <apex:column styleClass="inBorder">
  <apex:facet name="header">Product Name</apex:facet>
 <apex:outputText >{!Quotation1.ProductName__c}</apex:outputText>

  </apex:column>


  <apex:column styleClass="inBorder">
  <apex:facet name="header">Watt</apex:facet>
  <!--<apex:outputText>{!Product__c.Watt__c}</apex:outputText>-->
  </apex:column>


  <apex:column styleClass="inBorder">
  <apex:facet name="header">Quantity</apex:facet>
  <apex:outputText >{!Quotation1.Quantity__c}</apex:outputText>
  </apex:column>


  <apex:column styleClass="inBorder">
  <apex:facet name="header">Price</apex:facet>
 <apex:outputText >{!Quotation1.Price__c}</apex:outputText>
  </apex:column>
  <button onclick="up()">Add</button>
   <!--<button type="button">Click Me!</button>-->
    </apex:dataTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>

  <button onClick="myFunction()"> Download PDF </button>


   </apex:form>

  </apex:page>
```

Comment: A word of explanation would add meaning and improve the quality of your answer a lot. Know that you can always edit and update your questions and answers!