# Removing rows separately from the Visualforce pageBlockTable mandatory input field

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I've a pageBlockTable with inputField, I want to remove a single row and i know there is a good ans [Removing rows separately from the Visualforce pageBlockTable list](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10903/removing-rows-separately-from-the-visualforce-pageblocktable-list)
but if I hv mandatory inputfield the code doesn't work.

vf page:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="PO Items">  
       <!-- variable to keep track of poItemList index -->    
       <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNumber" />
       <apex:outputPanel id="panelWithVar">
          <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNumber" />
       </apex:outputPanel>

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!poItemList}" var="PO" title="PO Items" width="100%" id="Items">
              <apex:column headerValue="Remove">
                   <apex:commandLink value="X" action="{!removePoItem}" reRender="Items,panelWithVar">
                      <apex:param name="removeObj" value="{!"rowNumber"}" assignTo="{!removeNumber}"/>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column> 
                <apex:column headerValue="Inventory product">
                   <apex:inputField value="{!PO.Inventory_Product__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="UOM">
                   <apex:inputField value="{!PO.UOM__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
                   <apex:inputField value="{!PO.Quantity__c}"/>
                  <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber + 1}" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!addPoItems}" reRender="Items"/>
       </apex:pageBlock><br/><br/>
```

apex:

```
//TO add a Row of PO_Item
    public void addPoItems()strong text
    {
        poItemList.add(new PO_Item__c());                   
    }
 //Remove single elemnt from PO_Item
    public void removePoItem()
    {       
        poItemList.remove(removeNumber);                
    }
```

Comment: Do you get a message or exception or does it just silently not work? Just in case its a re-rendering issue, put an ID on the outer `apex:pageBlock` and include that ID in your `reRender` attribute.

Comment: Have you tried adding immediate="true" to your remove commandbutton, normally this skips the validation.